# Negative top margin + overflow:hidden on Boostrap carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have a generic bootstrap v3.7 carousel and I'm trying to pull it up over the content above it like this

[image]

This is done with a `margin-top: -50px;` on the teal div.  However, the hidden overflow property of the carousel is causing the top to be cut off above the top of the div, so I cannot achieve this overlay design.  My attempts to modify the CSS have only broken the carousel.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin-top should be applied the div containing `.carousel`, perhaps you are using it on the div with the calls `carousel`;

Following **code snippet** is what you're trying to achieve:

```css
.aboveCarousel {
  height: 300px;
  background: magenta;
}

.container {
  margin-top: -50px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='aboveCarousel'> </div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! I had the margin on the carousel class.  Adding another wrapping div and applying the margin to it worked perfect.